# Display data from the database into DropDownList in asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, html-select

I am trying to fetch field data from the database and display in dropdown list. I am not getting proper output. I get model class name in dropdown.

**Model** name: SearchMDLNoModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities
{
    public class SearchMDLNoModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Request For Id")]
        public string Request_For_Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DataLayer class** name :SearchMDLNoDL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities;
using DataLayer;
using System.Data;

namespace ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DataLayer
{
    public class SearchMDLNoDL
    {
        public static List<SearchMDLNoModel> getAllMDLno() //all details of SQue
        {
            string proc = "SPGetMDLno";
            DataTable table = DataProvider.SelectStoreProcedure(proc);
            List<SearchMDLNoModel> ListMDLno = new List<SearchMDLNoModel>();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                SearchMDLNoModel MDLno_Obj = new SearchMDLNoModel();
                MDLno_Obj.Request_For_Id = Convert.ToString(row["Request_For_Id"]);

                ListMDLno.Add(MDLno_Obj);
            }
            return ListMDLno;
        }

    }
}
```

**Controller** name: SearchMDLNoController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DataLayer;
using ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities;

namespace ApricaCRMEvent.Controllers
{
    public class SearchMDLNoController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /SearchMDLNo/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewData["MDLno"] = new SelectList(SearchMDLNoDL.getAllMDLno(),"Request_For_Id");

            return View();

        }

    }
}
```

**View** name: Index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ApricaCRMEvent.Models.CRM.DatabaseEntities.SearchMDLNoModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Search by MDLNo</h2>
  <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
  <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Profile Updation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
  Select MDLno 
  <%= Html.DropDownList("Request_For_Id", ViewData["MDLno"] as SelectList)%> 
  <input type="submit" value="search" name="SearchMDLNo" />  
  <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

I am getting output like this .. I want data of that particular field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [wrong constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460123%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of the `SelectList` where the second parameter is the 
`selectedValue`.

You probably need [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) where you can specify the `dataValueField` and the `dataTextField`

So you should write create your `SelectList` like this:

```
ViewData["MDLno"] = 
 new SelectList(SearchMDLNoDL.getAllMDLno(), "Request_For_Id", "Request_For_Id");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I get proper data in dropdownlitst. :)

Comment: I was knowing I need to pass 2 parameters but I was confused for what another parameter should I pass.