# how to get selected value of drop down list in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, html-select

This is my code [Display data from the database into DropDownList in asp.net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600467/display-data-from-the-database-into-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc3) 
In this I can now display data from database into dropdownlist but now I want that if I select any thing from dropdownlist data I want that selected value pass in my stored procedure. I know there is same question might be available or has already been asked but I am not getting my answer which I want. If anyone can explain me step by step or provide me some useful links.

Comment: you can try POST which passes the Data to the controller and from their you can use it in EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not completly tested and implemented.

You can acheive it using `onchange` event of `dropdownlist`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemValue,new {@onchange="passvalue(this);"})
```

Handle it using javascript and ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function passvalue(e){
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
         data: ({ selectedValue: e.innerHTML }),
         success: function (result) {
                                    },
         error: function (result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
      });
  }
  </script>
```

Now you can get the selected value to the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int selectedValue)
{
   // do whatever you want with `selectedValue`
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to achieve this:

Subscribe the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the dropdown and call the action method(with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for example) that passes the selected value to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches. One of the simplest is to have a ViewModel with a collection of SelectListItems to render in the drop-down and an item to take the selection. In my example code below of course I am using hard-coded values etc to demo the point!

**ViewModel**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TestListItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 1", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 1", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 1", Value = "1" },
            };
        }
    }

    public string SelectedItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<p>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemValue, new SelectList(Model.TestListItems, "Value", "Text"))</p>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new TestViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TestViewModel viewModel)
{
    string youChose = viewModel.SelectedItemValue;
    // ...
}
```

Also, to highlight the collection doesn't have to be of `SelectListItem` and could be another type. Then all you would need to do is change your view to perform a `.Select` to convert into a `SelectListItem`. For simplicity I've just made the ViewModel use it directly.